# Auth Fail Issue while creating a site

Tags: crafter-cms

I am getting the following error while creating a site on my local

> org.craftercms.deployer.api.exceptions.DeployerException: Failed to clone Git remote repository ssh://crafter@sampleserver.com:63022/opt/crafter/data/repos/sites/sample-site/published into /Users/parasjain/local-delivery/data/repos/sites/sample-site; nested exception is org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: ssh://crafter@sampleserver.com:63022/opt/crafter/data/repos/sites/sample-site/published: Auth fail
>       at org.craftercms.deployer.impl.processors.GitPullProcessor.cloneRemoteRepository(GitPullProcessor.java:150)
>       at org.craftercms.deployer.impl.processors.GitPullProcessor.doClone(GitPullProcessor.java:121)
>       at org.craftercms.deployer.impl.processors.GitPullProcessor.doExecute(GitPullProcessor.java:72)
>       at org.craftercms.deployer.impl.processors.AbstractMainDeploymentProcessor.execute(AbstractMainDeploymentProcessor.java:70)
>       at org.craftercms.deployer.impl.DeploymentPipelineImpl.executeProcessors(DeploymentPipelineImpl.java:76)
>       at org.craftercms.deployer.impl.DeploymentPipelineImpl.execute(DeploymentPipelineImpl.java:68)
>       at org.craftercms.deployer.impl.TargetImpl$DeploymentTask.run(TargetImpl.java:242)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

This is the command I am using

> ./init-site.sh -k /Users/parasjain/myprivatekey.key sample-site
>   ssh://crafter@sampleserver.com:63022/opt/crafter/data/repos/sites/sample-site/published

However with the same key and user name git clone works just fine

```
ssh-add /Users/parasjain/myprivatekey.key

git clone ssh://crafter@sampleserver.com:63022/opt/crafter/data/repos/sites/sample-site/published
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of error most commonly occurs when OpenSSH keys are used. Currently, CrafterCMS does not support OpenSSH keys. Please use RSA keys instead.

You can find documentation for troubleshooting [here](https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/system-administrators/deployer/debugging-deployer-issues.html)